# how to sum an amount product to initial productarray localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, shopping-cart

i'm following a course to learn javascript, but i got stuck somewhere !

I've created a custom sofa shop, with 3 pages for the moment : welcome page with all products, a custom page for each product, and a cart page.

I stock the cart products in the localstorage.

But I got a problem.

In the product page, we already have the option to choose what amount of the same article we want to add into the cart page. If the cart page, and the productarray in localstorage are empty, when we are adding an certain amount of a product, it will simply take the value of the input, and send to the local storage.

But, if i already have, for example, "blue sofa" x30 in my cart, and i return to the product page, and i send 40x "blue sofa" in the localstorage, instead of sum the already existing amount of "blue sofa" + what i just sent, it just update the amount, so delete the initial 30x "blue sofa" and replace it with 40x "blue sofa".

How can i fix it ? Thx in advance !

```
if (productArray == null) {
        productArray = [];
        productArray.push(fusionproductAndColor);
        productArray.amount += amountInput.value;
        localStorage.setItem("product", JSON.stringify(productArray));
    } else if (productArray != null) {
        for (i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++){
            console.log("test");
            if (productArray[i]._id == productDetails._id && productArray[i].color == select.value) {
                return (
                    productArray[i].amount = amountInput.value,
                    productArray.amount = this.amount += amountInput.value, 
                    console.log("quantite"),
                    localStorage.setItem("product",JSON.stringify(productArray))
                    (productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product")))
                );
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
            if (productArray[i]._id == productDetails._id && productArray[i].color != productDetails.color){
                return (
                    productArray.push(fusionproductAndColor),
                    localStorage.setItem("product",JSON.stringify(productArray))
                    (productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product")))
                );
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++) {
            if (productArray[i]._id != productDetails._id){
                return (
                    productArray.push(fusionproductAndColor),
                    localStorage.setItem("product",JSON.stringify(productArray))
                    (productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product")))
                );
```

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykkTs.png)

[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLBCz.png)

[code update screenshot 02/03/2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3gYK.png)

[last update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUVZD.png)

Comment: `fusionproductAndColor` is what? What does `productArray` look like typically? `productDetails._id` is meaningless...I know this is a segment of a bigger code but there's nothing declared and nothing to refer to so there isn't any idea of what values to expect...?

Comment: I will totally adjust my code citation, check it above  (thx for helping) !

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myObject = {
  amount:2
}

let myArray = [];

myArray.push(myObject);

console.log("value of myArray.amount:", myArray.amount);
console.log("value of myArray[0].amount:", myArray[0].amount);
```

In your first `if` block, try: `productArray[0].amount += amountInput.value;`

instead of: `productArray.amount += amountInput.value;`

(arrays do not have a property called amount but an object you just stored in element 0 of the new array could have).

I would have expected this to throw an error, visible on the developer console in your browser.

Comment: I don't have an error, but a problem with your suggestion. With this line, if i start from 0, if i add 9 sofas; in my localstorage, amount display : "99", because of 9 for productArray[i] and 9 for productArray[0]

Comment: @remsB digits read from input fields are in fact strings so the addition might concatenate rather than sum. e.g. "9" + "9" = "99" not 18. If this type of thing is occuring convert the value to an integer using parseInt(amountInput.value). Javascript can often simply coerce string digits to numbers but sometimes you have to tell them it's intended to be a number.

Comment: Didn't think about that ! I'll try this today and i tell you ! Thx !

Comment: thx ! i fixed the integers issue, but now i can't find the solution to get the initial productarray.amount and add the aountinput.amount to.  I'll update my post with new screens.

Comment: good luck. I would definitely look again at `productArray.amount`. If `productArray.amount += amountInput.value;` is not throwing an error then you have somewhere unintentionally assigned an object to a (non-array) variable named `productArray`. `productArray.amount` cannot reference the `.amount` property of an object stored in an array named `productArray`. It has to be `productArray[index].amount`.

Comment: I've solved the problem with productarray, everything around amount, but i found the problem with my course's mentor. First, i did the for loop in a wrong way, i made 3 for instead of only 1. But solved. Now, we simply have an issue with "(for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(productArray.length); i++)" . 
"i" never change when we click on add to cart, so it cause the for loop doing automatically 2 loops. any idea of why i dont want to increase by 1 on click ? I add a last screen

Comment: Does the console log of `productArray.length` agree with what you expect? I can only repeat that no array has a property called `.amount` and the reference `productArray.amount` is not pointing to what you image. If no error is thrown saying something like `amount is not a property of productArray`, you have mistakely assigned an object containing `.amount` to a variable called productArray.